# How to inject different services of the same type via action's parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired, symfony5

I have a simple controller with two actions. They have different output format so I want to inject different `Formatter` implementations in action's parameters. Is there a right way to do that?

```
class ProductController
{
    private ProductManager $productManager;

    public function __construct(ProductManager $productManager)
    {
        $this->productManager = $productManager;
    }

    public function search(Request $request, Formatter $formatter)
    {
        $query = $request->get('q');
        $response = $this->productManager->search($query);

        return new JsonResponse($formatter->format($response));
    }

    public function suggest(Request $request, Formatter $formatter)
    {
        $query = $request->get('q');
        $response = $this->productManager->suggest($query);

        return new JsonResponse($formatter->format($response));
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I would do is to change args name and explicitly [`bind`](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding) parameters in the configuration file, but I really don't know if there's a better way to reach this.

Comment: Unless you have a large number of Formatters, I would simply make child classes such as SearchFormatter and SuggestFormatter.  That makes the binding and aliases stuff go away.  If you do have a large number of formatters then you could also look into making a Service Locator just for formatters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type), if you have multiple implementations of the same type of service, you can declare the different types on the configuration, and bind each type to a different parameter name:

```yaml
services:
    # ...

    # Both these services implement the "Formatter" interface
    App\Util\SearchyFormatter: ~
    App\Util\SuggestyFormatter: ~

    # When you want to use the "SuggestyFormatter" implementation, you
    # type-hint for 'Formatter $suggestyFormatter'
    App\Util\Formatter $suggestyFormatter: '@App\Util\SuggestyFormatter'

    # This is the default implementation for the type
    App\Util\Formatter: '@App\Util\SearchyFormatter'
```

With this you can do:

```php
// since the parameter name does not match any of the existing declarations,
// the default will be used: App\Util\SearchyFormatter
public function search(Request $request, Formatter $formatter)
{
}

// and for this one, App\Util\SuggestyFormatter will be used instead
public function suggest(Request $request, Formatter $suggestyFormatter)
{
}
```

Comment: In principle, I like Symfony's ability to do this, but I feel like the var name is not really expressing "this will be a very different formatter", and at least comments should be added. I might have opted to add an empty interface that extends App\Util\Formatter (SuggestFormatter) and then set the Implementation for that interface and use the "talking" interface in services.yaml instead, which would make it more clear in code that those two are different. I feel variable names can be changed so easily with IDEs ... wouldn't like chaos only one refactor away.

Comment: Yes, I agree this seems a bit "leaky", and you end up with a weird, magical coupling between one service and the framework. It's the price to pay for magic. I do not like having empty interfaces to fulfil this kind of job either. If I really want to avoid magic, I just go for explicit configuration all the way. And in many cases I end up doing that, explicitly configuring services where I feel magic is convenient, but could end up being costly in the future.